# "What does prevent x from doing y?" OR "What prevents x from doing y?"

Tags: grammar, difference, do-support

Do you say:

> 1. What does prevent x from doing y?

OR

> 2. What prevents x from doing y?

My gut tells me it's the latter, but I can't explain it. It's just a feeling. What I'd like to know is what the actual rule is, and how do I know in other cases which form is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your gut is right.

If your interrogative pronoun is an object, then you get inversion with a dummy auxiliary "do":

> Cats chase mice → What do cats chase?

But if the pronoun is a subject, there is no inversion:

> Cats chase mice → What chases mice?

Now your example has a subject interrogative pronouns

> {something} prevents x from doing y  → What prevents x from doing y?

(You could also ask "What does {something} prevent x from doing?", or "What does {something} prevent from doing y?", but this is not your situation)

Comment: Note that "What _does_ prevent x from doing y?" can still be used, but in a specific circumstance where an earlier part of the conversation focused on what _doesn't_ prevent it. Similar example: "Lions chase mice, right? (response: No) What about tigers? (No) Dogs? (No) Elephants (No) Well then what **does** chase mice?"_ In this conversation, the "does" is used to distance itself from the prior examples, i.e. we talked about things that don't chase mice, so let's now talk about things that do chase mice.

Comment: And in most such usages the "does" is explicitly styled in some fashion to indicate emphasis, which also affects pronunciation.  Were you to omit the emphasis (in writing or in speech) you would usually be interpreted as incorrect rather than explicitly making that comparison.

Answer (score 24):

Generally speaking, you don't need auxiliary "do"-verbs in questions if the wh-word is the subject of the main verb.

In this case, "what" is the subject of "prevent", so we don't need "do".

We use the "do"-verb in subject questions when it's in the negative, or to add emphasis, especially to show contrast.

> I understand that those things don't prevent x from doing y, but what **does** prevent x from doing y? (emphasis to show contrast)

> What **does**n't prevent x from doing y? (negative question)

Comment: In a number of dialects, usage of ‘do’ to show contrast as suggested here may also be accompanied in spoken form by additional verbal stress on the ‘does’ or ‘doesn’t’ to further emphasize the contrast, especially if the speaker is trying to be sarcastic.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I'd go a step further and say the auxiliary "do" for emphasis/contrast *must* be stressed. Are you thinking of a counterexample, or a variety of English where the speakers don't stress this "do"?

Comment: I’ve heard some usage where it was not stressed beyond what would be normal for that point in a sentence, but not much, and not recently. Most of my choice of wording above is largely just an overabundance of caution, given how many things in English have seemingly random exceptions.

Answer (score 12):

Case 2 is the more usual form.  Case 1 could be used in very limited instances, in the form of a question, with an emphasis on *does*, to challenge an assumption that x is prevented from doing y.

Comment: or something like "Foo doesn't prevent x from doing y. What *does* prevent x from doing y?" - as contrast

Comment: Case 1 might also be seen outside of those instances in writing that's intended to sound antiquated (like certain fiction in a medieval setting, or perhaps very old documents). Having *do* in positions like that used to be optional in any context, but that hasn't been the case for centuries, so I don't recommend using it like that today.

Answer (score 2):

**What prevents** x from doing y?

**What** is the **subject** of the question. So the word order is the same as in a statement.

Statement: **It** prevents x from doing y. Question: **What** prevents x from doing y?

*What* can also be the object of a sentence. In this case, an  auxiliary verb (do, does, will etc.) comes before the subject.

What *does he* want? (what-object, he-subject)